# how to access a global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

consider this example:

```
/**/
var sizes;

$(window).resize(function() {

    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    //var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    if (viewportWidth > 1024) {
        sizes = '320';
    } else if (viewportWidth < 1024) {
        sizes = '300';
    }
}); /**/

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log(sizes);
    $('#full_width_anything_slider').anythingSlider({
        delay: sizes
    });

});​
```

how can i have access to the `sizes` var inside the other method?

right now it doesn't work

thanks

Comment: You are correctly declaring a global variable, however what you are passing into `anythingSlider` is a snapshot of what the value is, not a reference to a variable that contains that value. Changing the global variable will not change the delay of `anythingSlider` unless you re-initialize `anythingSlider` with the new value every time you change it (on resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the posted code is not wrapped in a function your declaration is global.

However if your viewportWidth is exactly 1024 sizes is never set. so do something like this:
`sizes` won't have a value until resize is called so set the value when you declare it and reset it when the window is resized

```
var sizes = $(window).width() <= 1024 ? '300' : '320';
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    sizes = $(window).width() <= 1024 ? '300' : '320';
});
```

be aware that global variables in general is a bad idea. In your case you might as well do

```
$(function() {
    $('#full_width_anything_slider').anythingSlider({
        delay: $(window).width() <= 1024 ? '300' : '320';
    });
});​
```

**note** the first part of the code will not really work with the way you are using it since, the value is passed to anythingSlider when the document is loaded and will not change when the window is resized (it's a value not a reference). The second part won't solve this problem either but repeating the code in window.resize like below will

```
var setupSlider = function()
    $('#full_width_anything_slider').anythingSlider({
        delay: $(window).width() <= 1024 ? '300' : '320';
    });
});​
$(function(){
    setupSlider();
});
$(window).resize(setupSlider);
```

Comment: care to comment on the DV. The code will solve the problem both issues with the code

Comment: im still testing the code. looks like this people are wright when they say that i need to re-initialize anythingSlider

Comment: `sizes = $(window).width() <= 1024 ? '300' : '320';` this works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sizes` has no value associated with it when your document onReady function executes.  In fact it will not have a value until your onResize function executes.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly declaring a global variable, however what you are passing into `anythingSlider` is a snapshot of what the value is, not a reference to a variable that contains that value. Changing the global variable will not change the delay of `anythingSlider` unless you re-initialize anythingSlider with the new value every time you change it (on resize)

It doesn't need to be global anyway.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var sizes = '0';
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    //var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    if (viewportWidth >= 1024) {
        sizes = '320';
    } else if (viewportWidth < 1024) {
        sizes = '300';
    }
    $('#full_width_anything_slider').anythingSlider({
        delay: sizes
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

Note however i can't find any documentation on re-initializing this plugin or changing it's options, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to re-initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very good practice... but:

```
/**/
$(window).resize(function() {
    updateSize();
}); /**/

function updateSize() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    //var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    if (viewportWidth > 1024) {
        sizes = '320';
    } else if (viewportWidth <= 1024) {
        sizes = '300';
    }
}    

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    updateSize();
    console.log(sizes);
    $('#full_width_anything_slider').anythingSlider({
        delay: sizes
    });

});​
```

I assume (and hope) you'll be using sizes at a later time as well?